# No suitable driver found for jdcb

Tags: java, sql, oracle

This is my first time doing sql work in Java, all I was doing was making a simple program where I open and close the connection

```
package exercises;

import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcEx1 {
    static Connection conn = null;
    static String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
    static String user = "labs";
    static String password = "labs";

    public JdbcEx1() {}

    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException {

        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
            conn.clearWarnings();
            System.out.println("Connection opened! for driver ==>Oracle 11XE");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(!conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Connection Close! Oracle");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run it I get the following error:

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE

I really don't have much of a clue as to whats going on, I've tried running through it with the debugger multiple times but that just confused me even more

Comment: You are missing the depency jar for the db provider.

Comment: @dambros is that the ojdbc6 file I had to put in the jre? I was just going by what my teacher told me to do (this is for class).

Comment: Make sure the oracle jdbc jar file is in your classpath ( file name can be ojdbc6.jar)

Comment: Eg :  java -cp .;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar JdbcEx1

Comment: Here's the file path I have ojdbc6.jar in

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext

Again, this is for class and I just put it where my teacher told me to.

Comment: If the jar is in  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext then your java command should be java -cp  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\ojdbc6.jar JdbcEx1

Comment: @elirevach I started searching and found the CORRECT path to make it work

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext

Comment: This is exactly the path i mention in my post

Answer (score 1):

The path of the `ojdbc6.jar` file that you points out:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext` ,

must be specified into the environment variable `CLASSPATH`.

> You need to have the ojdbc6.jar in your classpath environment variable
>   in order to have JDBC 4.0 standard support.